# icaclient on Kubuntu 14.04 x64

Tags: 64-bit, kubuntu, 14.04, citrix, icaclient

Has anybody been able to install the icaclient on Ubuntu/Kubuntu x64 successfully? Please respond with steps.

Greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is an excellent guide here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo

Comment: Thank you and I did use that guide however it didn't work for me. I was able to install icaclient 12.01 but no browser was able to detect the client.

Answer (score 1):

Just download the *.deb file from [here](http://www.citrix.com/downloads/citrix-receiver/linux/receiver-for-linux-130.html). Here is how to install.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
apt-get install lib32z1 lib32asound2
```

to
Once that is done, navigate where you've downloaded the file, most likely the Downloads folder, and run the command below:

```
dpkg -i icaclient_13.0.0.256735_amd64.deb
```

You can download `lib32asound2` from [here](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/139194357/lib32asound2_1.0.25-4ubuntu4_amd64.deb).  Once downloaded, you can install using `sudo dpkg -i ib32asound2_1.0.25-4ubuntu4_amd64.deb, or use Gdebi,`sudo apt-get install gdebi`

Comment: Thanks for your respond but 'lib32asound2' doesn't exist. Please see below for more information.

~$ sudo apt-get install lib32asoud2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package lib32asoud2

Comment: @nymg what about http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/a/alsa-lib/lib32asound2_1.0.25-4ubuntu3_amd64.deb

Comment: look at e added info in my answer.

Comment: @Cornelius - The deb package which you provide depends libasound2. The libasound2 can be installed in Trusty by installing liboss4-salsa-asound2 via aptitude/apt-get but it will apply the following changes. I am sort of afraid of applying it.

Comment: @nymg yes these are old unupdated packages...

Comment: @Mitch - I tried the package under you link and that also requires libasound2.

Comment: So I am assuming the installation of icaclient on 14.04 is not possible unless some legacy packages replaces the current ones. Also it is not clear that what are the side affects of using the legacy packages on 14.04.

Comment: Download from [here](http://pkgs.org/download/libasound2).

Comment: @Mitch - Thanks for the link, however I hope I can find a way to install the icaclietn without installing any legacy packages or at least not as this many.

Answer (score 1):

I got it installed using these commands:

```
sudo sudo apt-get install libasound2:i386
sudo dpkg -i --ignore-depends=ia32-libs,lib32asound2 icaclient_13.0.0.256735_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

The issue is that lib32asound2 is replaced by libasound2:i386 and ia32-libs is split up in several libfoo:i386 packages (which will be installed automatically). Telling dpkg to ignore these two packages was successful for me.

Answer (score 0):

just follow the [steps in Ubuntu Help site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo).

1- You basically need to download the package from here:

https://www.citrix.com/downloads/citrix-receiver/linux/receiver-for-linux-130.html

2- Install dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install libmotif4:i386 nspluginwrapper lib32z1 libc6-i386 libxp6:i386 libxpm4:i386 libasound2:i386
```

3- Make some changes to the package

```
cd ~/Downloads
mkdir ica_temp
dpkg-deb -x icaclient_13.0.0.256735_amd64.deb ica_temp
dpkg-deb --control icaclient_13.0.0.256735_amd64.deb ica_temp/DEBIAN
```

Edit the control file

```
sudo gedit ica_temp/DEBIAN/control
```

Change the line that starts with depends to:

Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.7-1), lib32z1, nspluginwrapper

Edit the post inst script

```
sudo gedit ica_temp/DEBIAN/postinst
```

Change line that says "echo $Arch|grep "i[0-9]86" >/dev/null" to

echo $Arch|grep -E "i[0-9]86|x86_64" >/dev/null

Repackage this modified version:

```
dpkg -b ica_temp icaclient-modified.deb
```

4- Install modified package

Double click the icaclient-modified.deb or use dpkg -i

5- Copy certificates

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/* /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts/
sudo c_rehash /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts
```

6- Configure remote drive access

```
/opt/Citrix/ICAClient/util/configmgr &
```

Done.

I did not come up with this solution. It is what is in Ubuntu Help site and it worked for me. My only problem is I can not move around Citrix Windows...